# How to assign default value if env var is empty?

Tags: go, environment-variables

How do you assign a default value if an environment variable isn't set in Go?

In Python I could do `mongo_password = os.getenv('MONGO_PASS', 'pass')` where `pass` is the default value if `MONGO_PASS` env var isn't set.

I tried an if statement based on `os.Getenv` being empty, but that doesn't seem to work due to the scope of variable assignment within an if statement. And I'm checking for multiple env var's, so I can't act on this information within the if statement.

Comment: An `if` _does_ work.

Comment: @Volker it does? I tried it with 

```
mpass := os.Getenv("MONGO_PASS")
    if len(mpass) == 0 {
      log.Println("MONGO_PASS env var not set, using mongo default")
      mpass := "pass"
    }```
And I get this:
`./server.go:63: mpass declared and not used`

Comment: Where line 63 aligns with mpass variable within the if block (I use mpass later on).

Comment: Figured it out. Should have been using `=` instead of `:=` on the `mpass` within the `if` statement. Thanks for calling me out Volker :-)

Answer (score 185, accepted):

There's no built-in to fall back to a default value,
so you have to do a good old-fashioned if-else.

But you can always create a helper function to make that easier:

```
func getenv(key, fallback string) string {
    value := os.Getenv(key)
    if len(value) == 0 {
        return fallback
    }
    return value
}
```

Note that as [@michael-hausenblas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/396567/michael-hausenblas) pointed out in a comment,
keep in mind that if the value of the environment variable is really empty, you will get the fallback value instead.

Even better as [@ŁukaszWojciechowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1223977/%C5%81ukasz-wojciechowski) pointed out, using [`os.LookupEnv`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#LookupEnv):

```
func getEnv(key, fallback string) string {
    if value, ok := os.LookupEnv(key); ok {
        return value
    }
    return fallback
}
```

Comment: Note that while above code is correct, you should be aware of the semantics: since it tests for length of the string `value` and the empty string `""` has length 0 it means that when the env variable is set to `""` you would get the fallback/default value rather than the value (which is trivially `""`). Really depends on your use case but I thought it's worth pointing out since I once ran into this semantic error and burnt a few cycles debugging it ;)

Comment: Instead of `Getenv` you could use `LookupEnv`. It also returns `ok boolean` status that the value was indeed there.

Answer (score 55):

What you're looking for is [`os.LookupEnv`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#LookupEnv) combined with an `if` statement.

Here is janos's answer updated to use LookupEnv:

```
func getEnv(key, fallback string) string {
    value, exists := os.LookupEnv(key)
    if !exists {
        value = fallback
    }
    return value
}
```

Answer (score 24):

Go doesn't have the exact same functionality as Python here; the most idiomatic way to do it though, I can think of, is:

```
mongo_password := "pass"
if mp := os.Getenv("MONGO_PASS"); mp != "" {
    mongo_password = mp
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Michael. I tried exactly that, which was similar to my initial attempt, and it complains that mongo_password inside of the if block isn't used (same error as my comment to Volker above. I thought this had sometime to do with the fact that variables within an if block were limited to that block, and couldn't get outside? Or am I mistaken, and that's declared variables... and my error is due to how I'm using the variable?

Comment: Note that the line `mongo_password := "pass"` is essential, because with this `mongo_password` is declared and defined (set to `pass` as the default value). If you don't have that line then I can imagine an error. In our case above, only `mp` has the local scope of the `if`, FWIW.

Comment: OHHHHHH. Light f'ing bulb. Thank you. I was mixing up declare (:=) and assignment (=). Works like a champ. You rock Michael.

Answer (score 21):

To have a clean code I do this:

```
myVar := getEnv("MONGO_PASS", "default-pass")
```

I defined a function that is used in the whole app

```
// getEnv get key environment variable if exist, otherwise return defaultValue
func getEnv(key, defaultValue string) string {
    value := os.Getenv(key)
    if len(value) == 0 {
        return defaultValue
    }
    return value
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Had the same question as the OP and found someone encapsulated the answers from this thread into a nifty library that is fairly simple to use, hope this help others!

https://github.com/caarlos0/env

Answer (score 2):

For more complex application you can use tooling such as `viper`, which allows you to set global custom default values, parse configuration files, set a prefix for your app's env var keys (to ensure consistency and name spacing of env var configurations) and many other cool features.

Sample code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/spf13/viper"
)

func main() {
    viper.AutomaticEnv() // read value ENV variable
    // Set default value
    viper.SetEnvPrefix("app")
    viper.SetDefault("linetoken", "DefaultLineTokenValue")

    // Declare var
    linetoken := viper.GetString("linetoken")

    fmt.Println("---------- Example ----------")
    fmt.Println("linetoken :", linetoken)
}
```

Comment: While this is a cooler and proper way for PROD app, it might be overkill for a simple/trivial app

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem and I just created a small package called [getenvs](https://gitlab.com/avarf/getenvs) exactly to answer this problem.

Getenvs supports `string`, `bool`, `int` and `float` and it can be used like below:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "gitlab.com/avarf/getenvs"
)

func main() {
    value := getenvs.GetEnvString("STRING_GETENV", "default-string-value")
    bvalue, _ := getenvs.GetEnvBool("BOOL_GETENV", false)
    ivalue, _ := getenvs.GetEnvInt("INT_GETENV", 10)

    fmt.Println(value)
    fmt.Println(bvalue)
    fmt.Println(ivalue)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you are OK with adding little dependency you can use something like https://github.com/urfave/cli

```
package main

import (
  "os"

  "github.com/urfave/cli"
)

func main() {
  app := cli.NewApp()

  app.Flags = []cli.Flag {
    cli.StringFlag{
      Name: "lang, l",
      Value: "english",
      Usage: "language for the greeting",
      EnvVar: "APP_LANG",
    },
  }

  app.Run(os.Args)
}
```