# How to resolve user environment variables in filepath

Tags: windows, go, environment-variables

Golang on windows. Trying to use

```
os.Open("%userprofile%\\myfile.txt")
```

Getting `file path not found` and golang is not resolving `%userprofile%` to my `C:\users\myusername` folder.

Comment: For POSIX shells you can use [os.ExpandEnv](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#ExpandEnv), but it doesn't seem to support the `%VAR%` style variables you're using. It would be trivial to implement your own version, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get a file handle, and make your program a little portable too, try

```
userprofile := os.Getenv("USERPROFILE")
f, err := os.Open(path.Join(userprofile, "myfile.txt"))
```

The `os.Getenv()` will read the environment variable and `path.Join()` will take care of properly constructing the path (so no need to do `\\`).

Instead of `os.Getenv()` you might also want to look at [`os.LookupEnv()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#LookupEnv). This will tell you if the environment variable you're looking for is empty or simply not existing. A good example of how you can use that to set default values can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40326540/how-to-assign-default-value-if-env-var-is-empty) answer on SO.

Answer (score 0):

```golang
userprofile := os.Getenv("USERPROFILE")
os.Open(userprofile+"\\myfile.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just written a package to do this. Feedback welcome

https://gitlab.com/stu-b-doo/windowspathenv/

```
fmt.Println(windowspathenv.Resolve("%USERPROFILE%/Documents"))

// C:\Users\YourName\Documents
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at http://www.golangprograms.com/how-to-set-get-and-list-environment-variables.html

You can read the 'userprofile' environment value and and build the path before passing it to os.Open

Comment: Link is not pointing there any more.